# UIImage imageWithXAssets

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimage, xcasset

Assume I have two assets in my project or I may have even more assets under my project.

[image: Multiple Assets] 
 
 
[image: Name of image]

- Question 1: I can have multiple assets in one project & that is valid, correct?
- Question 2: What if I set same name to an image-set in different xcode-assets? Example. "AppIcon" exists in `AppImages.xcassets` and `01 ConsumerSelectionVCtr.xcassets`. Why compiler is not showing me errors for same image-set in multiple `xcassets`.
- **Question 3**: How to load an image from xcassets?
- Question 4: Is it preferable to use xcassets for all images in project?

Answer (score 23):

See the [Asset Catalog documentation from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/_index.html)

1. Yes, and this may help you to organise images
2. I think one will overwrite the other. Don't give two 'images' the same name
3. As before, use `[UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage"]` for example
4. Yes, apps deployed to iOS 7 can take advantage of an Xcode feature which reduces your app's download time (Xcode does this automatically)

Comment: The link is now dead.

Comment: You also need to make sure the image is referenced in the project, not just inside the xcassets. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36786475/loading-a-uiimage-from-xcassets