# Loading a UIImage from xcassets

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, xcasset

I'm trying to load a launch image from the Image.xcassets folder but to no avail.  There are other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19294589/uiimage-imagewithxassets)s (and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32152197/how-to-load-image-from-images-xcassets-into-a-uiimage-with-swift)) on SO that purport to answer it but their main solution, to simply load an image like so

```
UIImage *image =  [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default@2x"];
```

returns nil for me.

The filename is named correctly and the project is setup to use the assets.

Does anyone have any idea how I do this or what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

[image: screenshot of my assets folder]

EDIT 2: my final code:

```
-(void) loadSplashImage{
if ([self isiPad]){
    self.imageViewSplash.image =  [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Portrait"];
}
else{
    if (self.view.frame.size.height == 480){
        self.imageViewSplash.image =  [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default"];
    }
    else if (self.view.frame.size.height == 568){
        self.imageViewSplash.image =  [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-568h"];
    }
    else if (self.view.frame.size.height == 667){
        self.imageViewSplash.image =  [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-667h"];
    }
}
```

}

Please note it works for Portrait only.

Comment: You have to give the asset name not the image name.

Comment: I've also tried adding Default.png (now obsolete) to the assets as well.

Comment: Check answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/32945986/3202193

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You dont have to specify the size of the image in your name. It will automatically load the size that best fits for the device that runs the app. So your code should be.

```
UIImage *image =  [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default"];
```

where default is the name of the resource from `xcassets`, the one you see on the leftside list.

Comment: Thanks Jelly but I'm still getting nil.

Comment: Well post a screenshot of your `xcassets ` so we can see how it looks like

Comment: You have to put them in xcode, because they won't be picked up if you just put them in a folder.

Comment: You should have a `Assets.xcassets` file in your xcode project. Open that and there should your resources go in. Check more about assets catalogs here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/_index.html .

Comment: Adding a reference to them in XCode did the trick. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the way to get LaunchImage name.

[Xcode 5 & Asset Catalog: How to reference the LaunchImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19107543/xcode-5-asset-catalog-how-to-reference-the-launchimage/27797958#27797958)

Getting image name from info.plist (`[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary]`)

Answer (score 0):

You should have 2 files:

(1) Default.png (or any other image format) — Non retina

(2) Default@2x.png  — Retina

Now, to get this image, you will not have to use @2x at the end of the file name. Use just name of that image asset.

Comment: Thanks NSPratik but I still get nil.

Comment: Try with name other than "Default"